# OLS Regression in R

Tags: r, regression, combinations

I am really struggling with the following problem set using R
.
I want to simulate a data set with one dependent and 20 independent variables that are normally i.i.d.. Each variable should have 100 observations. (I managed to do this part)

(Now the part I am struggling with):
My plan is to conduct automated regressions for all possible combinations of up to 5 regressor using an own coded regression function that simulates the output of summary(lm) that uses a vector y and a matrix or vector x as input (so my.lm(y,x)). And then bringing the results in a suitable data structure.

I would be thankful for every hint!

Comment: Have you seen how many combinations are there of 20 by 5? `choose(20, 5)` returns `[1] 15504`. Plus `choose(20, 4)`, `choose(20, 3)`, `choose(20, 2)`, `choose(20, 1)`. Not my downvote but your routine has a point?

Comment: Yes I already covered how many combinations are possible. I am struggling how to get each combination in a data structure form.

Comment: This i the approach i tried.
table <- matrix(0, nrow = 21699, ncol = 20)
row <- 0
for(idx in 1:ncol(table)) {
  table[idx,idx] <- 1
  row <- row + 1
}
x <- 2
for(idx1 in 1:ncol(table)) {
for(idx2 in x :ncol(table)) {
  table[row+1, idx1] <- 1
  table[row+1, idx2] <- 1
  row <- row + 1
  x <- x+1
}
}

Comment: @falkialki, you should add what you have tried (i.e. what you wrote in your comment) in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt the soundness of what you are trying to do but here it goes.
I will make up a dataset, since you have not posted one.

```
my.lm <- function(x, y, n = 5){
  f <- function(inx){
    inx_cols <- Combn[inx, ]
    inx_cols <- inx_cols[inx_cols != 0]
    X <- as.data.frame(x[, inx_cols])
    names(X) <- paste0("X", inx_cols)
    X <- cbind(X, y)
    name_y <- names(X)[length(names(X))]
    fmla <- as.formula(paste(name_y, ".", sep = "~"))
    tryCatch(lm(fmla, data = X), error = function(e) e)
  }

  nc_x <- ncol(x)
  nr <- sum(choose(nc_x, seq_len(n)))
  Combn <- matrix(0, nrow = nr, ncol = n)
  first <- 1
  for(i in seq_len(n)){
    last <- first + choose(nc_x, i) - 1
    Combn[first:last, seq_len(i)] <- t(combn(nc_x, i))
    first <- last + 1
  }

  apply(Combn, 1, f)
}

set.seed(6876)

regr <- replicate(20, rnorm(100))
coefs <- sample(-5:5, 20, TRUE)
resp <- regr %*% coefs + rnorm(100)

lm_list <- my.lm(regr, resp)
length(lm_list)
#[1] 21699
```

So the function above produced as many objects as expected.
Before continuing, let's see how many are errors (singular matrix, for instance).

```
err_list <- lapply(lm_list, function(x){
  if(inherits(x, "error")) x else NULL
})
err_list <- err_list[!sapply(err_list, is.null)]
length(err_list)
#[1] 0
```

No errors.
So get the summaries of the objects of class `"lm"`.

```
good_list <- lapply(lm_list, function(x){
  if(inherits(x, "lm")) x else NULL
})
good_list <- good_list[!sapply(good_list, is.null)]

smry_list <- lapply(good_list, summary)
smry_list[[1]]
#
#Call:
#  lm(formula = fmla, data = X)

#Residuals:
#    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#-34.654  -9.487  -1.985   9.486  50.213 

#Coefficients:
#                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept)       0.6449     1.5237   0.423    0.673    
#X1               -7.3969     1.5074  -4.907 3.68e-06 ***
#  ---
#  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 15.02 on 98 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.1972,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.189 
#F-statistic: 24.08 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: 3.684e-06
```